# Need help to understand the meaning of タチが悪いのよ in this context (1 of MC's big sister is saying that his other 2 sisters are acting too easy with him)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

**Context:** 1 of MC's older sister said with his other 2 big sisters, that they're spoiling him /acting too easy with MC.

Appreciates if someone can explain to me the meaning of this sentence "二人とも無自覚でそう言うこというから、タチが悪いのよ"

My guess based on the context is: "I'm angry because you 2 said that(?) so nonchalantly, didn't even realized that you guys are acting too easy with him."?

Full conversation below:

> 春佳 (Eldest sister)「ふふ、はあ君ったら、そんなにジッと見つめられたら、お姉ちゃん、ちょっと照れちゃうかも」
>
> 俺の視線に気がついた春姉が頬を赤らめながら、身体をモジモジとさせる。
>
> 冬花 (2nd sister)「なんとなくだけど、やらしい視線だった。もしかして、姉相手に欲情してる、とか？」
>
> 夏希 (3rd and MC's youngest big sister)「は～や～て～」
>
> モジモジしてる春姉と、ニンマリとした顔で俺を見る冬姉に、夏姉がジト目で俺を睨む。
>
> 疾風 (MC)「ちょっと待った！　欲情なんてしてないって、俺はただいつものやり取りだなぁって思って見てただけだよ」
>
> 春佳「うふふ、冗談よ。冬花も夏希も、はあ君をあんまり苛めたりしたらダメだからね」
>
> 夏希「あたしは別に苛めたりなんてしてないってば」
>
> 冬花「春姉だけ、いい子ぶるのはＮＧだから。でも、夏希はやっぱり疾風に厳しすぎかもね。苛めてるとは思わないけど」
>
> 夏希「あたしは普通です。二人があまあまなだけでしょ」
>
> 春佳「そう？」
>
> 冬花「あたしは普通だと思ってるけど」
>
> **夏希「はぁ～、二人とも無自覚でそう言うこというから、タチが悪いのよ」**
>
> 春佳「まあまあ、細かいことは気にせずに朝食にしましょう、ね」

Answer (score 3):

I think [jisho.org's explanation](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%B3%AA%E3%81%8C%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84) is misleading in this case. タチが悪い in this context is "difficult to deal with". Natsuki is not saying the other two have an evil personality, but is saying their personalities make the situation unnecessarily messy. The kanji for タチ is 質, but it's typically written in kana in this idiom because 質 is also read as しつ. タチが悪い never means "I'm angry".

For example, one can say:

> 彼女は素直な性格だけにタチが悪い。
>
> She is honest, and that's what makes the problem worse.
> She is difficult to deal with all the more for her honesty.

Your understanding of 二人とも無自覚でそう言うこという seems fine. Natsuki is basically saying that the other two sisters are too 甘い.